# Flask-SocketIO doesn't work on Azure

Tags: javascript, jquery, azure-web-app-service, flask-socketio

I have a website that works perfectly when I host it locally, but on Azure the socketio requests result in an http 400 error. It is a Python flask app that uses flask-socketio. The socket I connect to locally is 'http://127.0.0.1:5000,' but on Azure I connect to http://myurl.azurewebsites.net:80 because the Azure documentation says it listens on ports 80 and 443. I'm using javascript with jquery and this is how I create the socket:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://myurl.azurewebsites.net:80');
```

I've found many questions from people who had this issue, but they all seem to be using node.js, and the solution involves the node.js require() method. I can't find a solution using just javascript or jquery. Is this even possible? Thanks.

Comment: Who listens on port 80? Are you running your own server on 80, or is Azure adding something on port 80 that forwards to your app on 5000? If that is how you have this set up, then likely the problem is that the Azure reverse proxy does not support Socket.IO routing, which has a few requirements. See the deployment docs on the Flask-SocketIO documentation for details.

Comment: @Miguel I'm using port 80 because the Azure documentation says it listens on port 80. I also tried the default port 5000 and that didn't work. Also this is how I start the app in the python file: `socketio.run(app, host='http://myurl.azurewebsites.net', port='80')`

Comment: @Luciano Hi,any progress now?

Comment: @Luciano Does my answer helps you?Any updates?

Comment: @JayGong I tried that same sample. I had to clear out and update requirements.txt. I deployed it as a webapp on Azure, enabled sockets, but see these types of errors: WebSocket connection to 'wss://MYSITE.azurewebsites.net/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503

Answer (score 0):

I  tried to reproduce your issue but failed. I followed the sample [here](https://github.com/prashanthmadi/azure-appservice-py-websocket).
After deploying to Azure, installing the requirements and enabling Web Sockets in Azure `portal > App > Application Settings`, it works all fine.Please refer to my components.

[image]

***Output***:

[image]

***My web.config***:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <webSocket enabled="true" />
  <handlers>
   <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  </handlers>

  <httpPlatform processPath="D:\home\Python27\python.exe" arguments="run_waitress_server.py" requestTimeout="00:04:00" startupTimeLimit="120" startupRetryCount="3" stdoutLogEnabled="true">
   <environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot" />
    <environmentVariable name="PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
   </environmentVariables>
  </httpPlatform>

</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Hope it helps you.